# Having trouble solving simple ode - need help.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a trouble of solving this rather simple ode :

```
x(t),y(t),z(t)

x' = y + z
y' = x + z
z' = x + y
```

The way we should solve it for a class is by merging all three into one differential equation and then solving that equation to get the one unknown and from there get the others.

If you can help me, that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: $x'- y' = y-x$, $y'-z' = z- y$, $x'-z' = = z-x$, etc.

Comment: Just for you to know, this is not a pde, its an ode

Comment: I am sorry for bad naming - don't know why I had that pde instead of ode in my head :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider the following:

Given that $x'=y+z$ and $y'=x+z$, then:
$$x'+y'=x+y+2z$$

Now as $z'=x+y$, then the above eqaution turns into:
$$z''=z'+2z$$
Considerig you can solve the equation for $z$, lets  assume it is a known function $z=f(t)$, then:
$$f'(t)-x=y$$
Replacing this in the equation of $x'$, you would get:
$$x'=f'(t)-x+f(t)$$
Assuming $x=g(t)$ the equation for $y$ would be:
$$y'=g(t)+f(t)$$
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Since they are three first order ODEs, the solution must contains three arbitrary constants.

$\begin{cases}
x'=y+z \\
y'=x+z \\
z'=x+y
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad 
\begin{cases}
x'+y'+z'=2(x+y+z) \\
u=x+y+z \quad\to\quad u'=2u \quad\to\quad u=c_1e^{2t}
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
u=x'+x=c_1e^{2t} \quad\text{linear ODE}\quad\to\quad x=\frac{c_1}{3}e^{2t}+c_2e^{-t} \\
u=y'+y=c_1e^{2t} \quad\text{linear ODE}\quad\to\quad y=\frac{c_1}{3}e^{2t}+c_3e^{-t}
\end{cases}$

$$z=u-x-y \quad\to\quad z=\frac{c_1}{3}e^{2t}-(c_2+c_3)e^{-t}$$